# Testing a WSDL in Eclipse Web Services Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL file for a web service which i want to test. Im using the Web Services Explorer in Eclipse to test the webservice. The webservice defines a login operation,containing a loginRequest message. The definitions are as shown below.

**Login Operation**

```
  <wsdl:operation name="login" parameterOrder="in0">

     <wsdl:input message="impl:loginRequest" name="loginRequest"/>

  </wsdl:operation>
```

**loginRequest Message**

```
<wsdl:message name="loginRequest">

      <wsdl:part name="in0" type="tns1:CompiereBean"/>

</wsdl:message>
```

**CompiereBean object**

```
<complexType name="CompiereBean">
    <sequence>
     <element name="loginDetails" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"/>
     <element name="productList" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"/>
     <element name="quantityList" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"/>
     <element name="tenantDetails" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

**ArrayOf_xsd_anyType**

```
<complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_anyType">

<complexContent>
<restriction base="soapenc:Array">
<attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]"/>
</restriction>
</complexContent>

</complexType>
```

Now, to test the webservice, i right click on the WSDL file->Web Services->Test with Web Services Explorer. I now get a form in the Actions pane,with fields for specifying loginDetails,productList,quantityList and tenantDetails.

So, my question is since loginDetails,productList,quantityList and tenantDetails are all ArrayList objects, how to input their values ?

Comment: What exactly is the definition of `impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType` in your WSDL? We can guess and probably come near it, but it would be much better if we didn't have to guess.

Comment: Ive updated my question with the definition of impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType

Comment: I suggest you to try testing your web services with SoapUI (http://www.soapui.org/). It is a free tool with a very friendly interface to test web services. From the WSDL it will create a request for testing your service, you only need to replace the "?" with the values...

Comment: Thanks for the reply JuanZe . I installed SoapUI. Created a new project in SoapUI and added my WSDL. Now, in the request area it shows the following XML (http://pastie.org/804081), but there are no question marks..what could be going wrong here ?

Comment: @blackpanther I have reverted your [proposed edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1991919#./1991919) because first, you didn't correct any grammar as you claimed (you just changed it) and second, you changed a code snippet. That's a no-go and I won't accept that. If you're bored enough to suggest such minor improvements then I suggest that you at least leave the code snippets alone (except for meaningless whitespace). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you an example and maybe it can help you.

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

public class Thing implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4205832525113691806L;
    private String name;
    private Date date;
    private Long longg;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public Long getLongg() {
        return longg;
    }
    public void setLongg(Long longg) {
        this.longg = longg;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Thing [name=" + name + ", date=" + date + ", longg=" + longg + "]";
    }
}
```

and the web service

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
@Stateless
public class WS {   
    public void doSomething(Thing[] things){
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(things));
    }
}
```

then if you use soapUI to generate the request for you, you'll get something like this

[image]

and the result will be (in your server logs)

```
[Thing [name=aeoliam venit, date=Sun Sep 28 22:49:45 BRT 2008, longg=10]]
```

but, of course, you want to send an array of these things, so...

[image]

and voila, the result will be

```
[Thing [name=aeoliam venit, date=Sun Sep 28 22:49:45 BRT 2008, longg=10], Thing [name=aeoliam venit, date=Sun Sep 28 22:49:45 BRT 2008, longg=10]]
```

gotcha? :-)

it´s incredible that we just can't find anywhere this answer.